# strange result in using python's property

Tags: python, properties

I spent some time to learn Python's property magic. But when I am writing a simple case with a small mistake, I get a strange result. Here is my code:

```
class PropertyShow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__num = 90 

    def setNum(self,value):
        self.__num = value

    def getNum(self):
        return self.__num

    def delNum(self):
        del self.__num

    #num = property(getNum,setNum,delNum)
    # I made a mistake here!
    __num = property(getNum,setNum,delNum)


class PropertyTwo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__num = None

    @property
    def num(self):
        """OK, use a decorator, you can do something here!"""
        return self.__num

    @num.setter
    def num(self,value):
        self.__num = value

    @num.deleter
    def num(self):
        del self.__num

one = PropertyShow()
print one.num 
two = PropertyTwo()
print two.num
```

In the key line, "num = property(getNum,setNum,delNum)". I changed this line to this careless, now like this "__num = property(getNum,setNum,delNum)".

The result of this code:

```
File "property.py", line 6, in setNum
    self.__num = value
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

1. Why do I get this unexpected result when replacing `num` to `__num`?
2. How to understand the magic of `property()` and why should one use private variables?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `self.__num = value` results in the property setter being invoked.

The property setter tries to set `self.__num`, which results in the property setter being invoked. The property setter tries to set `self.__num`, which results in the property setter being invoked. The property setter tries to set `self.__num`, which results in the property setter being invoked. The property setter tries to set `self.__num`, which results in the property setter being invoked. The property setter tries to set `self.__num`, which results in the property setter being invoked. The property setter tries to set `self.__num`, which results in the property setter being invoked. The property setter tries to set `self.__num`, which results in the property setter being invoked. The property setter tries to set `self.__num`, which results in the property setter being invoked.

Infinite recursion detected.

When your property is *not* named `__num`, this obviously does not happen.

To be explicit: Python sees the line `self.__num = value` as a `STORE_ATTR` opcode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def setNum(self, value):
...     self.__num = value
... 
>>> dis.dis(setNum)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (value)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              6 STORE_ATTR               0 (__num)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

The implementation for `STORE_ATTR` will first look for a data descriptor on the class, and finds your `__num` `property` object. The call is then effectively translated to:

```
PropertyShow.__num.__set__(self, value)
```

The `property` object looks up the configured setter function, which is `PropertyShow.setNum` and calls it as `PropertyShow.setNum(self, value)`. This in turn calls `self.__num = value` again and recursion takes over from there.

Comment: So what happens when the property setter tries to set `self.__num` again exactly?

Comment: @JonClements: There, better?